# JDBC not connecting on Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, linux, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL server in Google Apps Script. I am able to connect through MySQL Workbench from my PC and with MySQL from another server, I tested permissions, I can insert and other stuff.

This is the code I have in Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
var server = "zikovi.eu";
var port = 3306;
var username = "test";
var database = "testdb";
var password = "testpwd";

var url = "jdbc:mysql://"+server+":"+port+"/"+database;
Logger.log(url);

var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

No matter what, the error says to check the URL, username or password. The parameters are correct (you can check, it's a test user and db).

Comment: Did you whitelist Google ips? Your sql server logs should provide connection rejection reason. Did you check the logs?

Comment: Are you using MySQL version 8.0.X?  I wasted an entire weekend trying to make the connection work when I finally saw a comment on SO that mentioned Google's JDBC driver only works with version 5,7.X or less.  Once I downgraded MySQL to 5.7 it worked for me.